# Sensor ultrasónico de Arduino

Tags: arduino

¿Puedo modificar el rango de medición del sensor? por ejemplo en lugar de que el rango sea de 2cm a 400cm, que sea de 2cm a 100cm.

Comment: ¿Cual sensor? ¿Qué dice el manual?

Comment: el sensor ultrasonico

Comment: https://leantec.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Leantec.ES-HC-SR04.pdf

Comment: Cómo dice el manual, *Para saber a la distancia a la que se encuentra el objeto, solo hay que medir el tiempo al que está el pin Echo a nivel alto y aplicar la siguiente formula: Centimetros = uS x 0,01715*